# How to prevent Django to initialize "prod" DB before test DB

Tags: django

I'm using Django for the backend of my project and I'm currently writing tests.
The thing is when I use the command `python manage.py test`, it first loads my actual DB before creating the test DB.

The problem is that on DB initialization, I have some processes that do stuff with the App Registry (in my software you can install/uninstall apps while Django is running).

So when I use the `test` command, it loads my App Registry from my local DB, then it creates the test DB but it seems to be using the same App Registry (since it uses the same settings when it starts).

So I have tests that fail because things are already done in the App Registry (because of my local DB), that shouldn't be.

So when I do `python manage.py test`, the output is :

> I do this : `print("DB : ", connection.settings_dict['NAME'])` somewhere to show you

```
DB :  my-db
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
.DB :  test_my-db
.....
(...tests are executed here...)
....
```

You can see that `my-db` is loaded before `test_my-db` is created to be used in tests.

Is there any setting that I could use to tell Django :
"Hey, I'm using the `test` command, do not load my local DB first !" ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Well at initialisation, I have a method `load_applications()` that looks into the DB for marked installed applications, and add it to the registry and then reset the app registry to populate `INSTALLED_APPS`.

I just made :

```py
if sys.argv[1] != "test":
   Application.load_applications()
```

So that they aren't loaded if the used command is `test`...

However I'm still wondering why the local DB is "loaded" when running tests ?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`. You can create two different setting files one for production and another for tests. Then edit `manage.py` to change the settings module according to the environment you want to activate

```
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = 'settigns/file/path'
```

Or you might simply use `export` and not edit `manage.py`

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=relative.settigns.file.path
python manage.py test
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For example in `prod.py` settings file, we'll have:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.mysql",
        "HOST": "mysql_host_ip",
        "NAME": "dbname",
        "PASSWORD": "thepaswword",
        "PORT": "3306",
        "USER": "root"
    },
}
```

and in `tests.py` we can have:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': "temp.db",
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True,
    },
}
```

Comment: You suggest to do it to give a different DB_NAME that shouldn't exist locally ?

Comment: Actually I didn't think about it. Interesting to do it like this then. Pretty obvious after all. Question : Why do you set ATOMIC_REQUESTS to True in the settings that are defined tests.py here ?

Comment: `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` is just a common approach when you run tests